# Word equivalent to "intellectual challenge"

Tags: synonyms, single-word-requests

Is there a word that is equivalent to the phrase 'intellectual challenge'?

Comment: What's wrong with *intellectual challenge*? In what context would something different be used? Can you provide an example sentence with an empty space for the word?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I'm just picky :). An example sentence would be, "I enjoy mathematics and its intellectual challenges"

Comment: You just used *intellectual challenges* in a sentence. That doesn't help in any way in terms of some kind of replacement. If there's nothing wrong with *intellectual challenges*, then just use it. If you *don't* have some reason for not using it, then I can't understand your question. This is not a *discussion* site but one where specific objective answers can be provided . . .

Comment: Beware, though. The phrase has been coined as a politically correct expression and is not to be substituted in general writing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many that go around this idea (paradox, theory, riddle, quandary, etc...)

However, for the aspect of "challenge," specifically, I would propose:

[conundrum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conundrum)

> 1a : an intricate and difficult problem
>
> 1b : a question or problem having only a conjectural answer

This especially hits on the "intellectual" nature, since **[conjectural](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjectural)** means that whatever answer you come up with cannot be 'physically' proven or tested: *you just have to be right*.